# Django 2.0 using views.py to render a html page (TemplateDoesNotExist)

Tags: python, django

still learning the basics of Django and I'm struggling a little. Right now I'm trying to create a home page for my site. The project name is 'meal_planner' and the app is 'meal_plans'.

meal_planner/urls.py contains this code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'', include('meal_plans.urls', namespace='meal_plans'))
    path('', include('meal_plans.urls', namespace='meal_plans'))
]
```

meal_plans/urls.py contains this code:

```
"""Define URL patterns for meal_plans"""
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'meal_plans'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

and meal_plans/views.py contains this code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    """Homepage"""
    return render(request, 'main\index.html')
```

The error I'm getting is

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
main\index.html

Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ...\meal_planner\mp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\main\index.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: ...\meal_planner\mp\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\main\index.html (Source does not exist)
```

I've tried searching on how to do this but I just can't get it right. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one directory `templates` inside `meal_plans`, then add your `index.html` to that directory. Then, change your code as below,

```
def index(request):
    """Homepage"""
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```